# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing while pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['Rawdata_2001to2018.csv']

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I get this message with the code. Can you help me
File "", line 93
"state":str})
^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

```
    \\\ Codes
         import pandas as pd import numpy as np import io Rawdata_2001to2018_df = 
         pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['Rawdata_2001to2018.csv'].encoding('ISO-8859-1'), dtype= 
     {"gvkey":str, "datadate": str, "fyear": str, "indfmt": str, "consol": str, "popsrc": str, 
     "datafmt": str, "tic": str, "cusip": str, "conm": str, "curcd": str, "fyr": str, "act": int, 
      "at": int, "ceq": int, "ceqt": int, "ch": int, "che": int, "cogs": int, "csho": int, "dd1": 
      int, "dlc": int, "dltt": int, "dp": int, "emp": int, "ibc": int, "invt": int, "lct": int, 
      "mib": int, "ni": int, "oancf":int, "oibdp": int, "ppegt": int, "ppent": int, "pstk": int, 
      "rect": int, "rectr": int, "rmum": int, "sale":int, "spi": int, "xad": int, "xi": int, "xido": 
      int, "xidoc": int, "xopr": int, "xrd": int, "xsga": int, "exchg": str, "cik": str, "costat": 
     str, "fic": str, "prcc_c": int, "mkvalt": int, "prcc_f": int, "au": str, "auop": str, "ceq_dc": 
     str, "ceqt_dc": str, "ch_dc": str, "che_dc": str, "csho_dc": str, "dd1_dc": str, "dlc_dc": str, 
    "dltt_dc":str, "do_dc": str, "dp_dc": str, "emp_dc": str, "ib_dc": str, "ibc_dc": str, "invt_dc": 
    str, "mib_dc": str, "ni_dc": str, "oibdp_dc": str, "ppegt_dc": str, "pstk_dc":str, "rect_dc": 
    str, "rectr_dc": str, "spi_dc": str, "xad_dc": str, "xi_dc": str, "xido_dc" : str, "xidoc_dc": 
    str, "xrd_dc": str, "xsga_dc":str, "city":str, "county":str, "fyrc":str, "local":str, "sic":str, 
    "state":str})\\\
```

Comment: Please share what uploaded['Rawdata_2001to2018.csv'] looks like

Answer (score 0):

- Change your code as below **\/**

```py
  import pandas as pd 
  import numpy as np 
  import io 
  Rawdata_2001to2018_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['Rawdata_2001to2018.csv'].encoding('ISO-8859-1')), dtype= {"gvkey":str, "datadate": str, "fyear": str, "indfmt": str, "consol": str, "popsrc": str, 
     "datafmt": str, "tic": str, "cusip": str, "conm": str, "curcd": str, "fyr": str, "act": int, 
      "at": int, "ceq": int, "ceqt": int, "ch": int, "che": int, "cogs": int, "csho": int, "dd1": 
      int, "dlc": int, "dltt": int, "dp": int, "emp": int, "ibc": int, "invt": int, "lct": int, 
      "mib": int, "ni": int, "oancf":int, "oibdp": int, "ppegt": int, "ppent": int, "pstk": int, 
      "rect": int, "rectr": int, "rmum": int, "sale":int, "spi": int, "xad": int, "xi": int, "xido": 
      int, "xidoc": int, "xopr": int, "xrd": int, "xsga": int, "exchg": str, "cik": str, "costat": 
     str, "fic": str, "prcc_c": int, "mkvalt": int, "prcc_f": int, "au": str, "auop": str, "ceq_dc": 
     str, "ceqt_dc": str, "ch_dc": str, "che_dc": str, "csho_dc": str, "dd1_dc": str, "dlc_dc": str, 
    "dltt_dc":str, "do_dc": str, "dp_dc": str, "emp_dc": str, "ib_dc": str, "ibc_dc": str, "invt_dc": 
    str, "mib_dc": str, "ni_dc": str, "oibdp_dc": str, "ppegt_dc": str, "pstk_dc":str, "rect_dc": 
    str, "rectr_dc": str, "spi_dc": str, "xad_dc": str, "xi_dc": str, "xido_dc" : str, "xidoc_dc": 
    str, "xrd_dc": str, "xsga_dc":str, "city":str, "county":str, "fyrc":str, "local":str, "sic":str, 
    "state":str})
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I did it and I a getting this message "import io Rawdata_2001to2018_df ="    Can you help?

Comment: Thx. I tried it and I am getting the numpy erro